# How to get Products by ids & Collections with filter using ShopifyAPI::GraphQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, graphql

Before I have these:

**Getting Products by product_ids**

```
shopify_client #shopify_session
ShopifyAPI::Product.all(:params => 
{:page => 1, :limit => 250, :ids => product_ids})
```

**Getting Collections, filter by product_id & specific field**

```
ShopifyAPI::Collect.find(:all, 
params:{product_id: product_id, fields: 'collection_id'})
```

Now I'm migrating to GraphQL, how can I achieve the same result as REST?

Here is sample GraphQL query:

```
# Once your session is activated, simply construct a new graphql client and use `parse` and `query`


client = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new

SHOP_NAME_QUERY = client.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
  {
    shop {
      name
    }
  }
GRAPHQL

result = client.query(SHOP_NAME_QUERY)
result.data.shop.name
```

**Reference Gem:** https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/pull/431

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you mean that you're migrating to using Shopify's GraphQL API?

Comment: @RyanBigg yes, doing like { shop { name } } ....

Comment: Is your question, what the query should look like, or generally how you set it up, so you can consume the Shopify GraphQL API?

Comment: @RolandStuder I updated the question and added sample successful query.